# How do I connect a signal to a slot in a static method?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to show a popup window from within a static method:

```
 void MainThread::popup(void){
 static klassePopup* roiPopup;
 roiPopup = new SavingROI();
 roiPopup->show();}
```

This code works fine, I get my window with two QPushbuttons, but I don't understand when I should connect the SIGNAL `clicked()` with a SLOT.

The following code didn't work:

```
 connect(roiPopup->getsaveROIButton(),SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(saveROI(cv::Mat)));
```

I know that the question isn't clear but the code is little bit complicated to copy here

Comment: Where is the static method you talk about in the title?

Comment: popup is my static methode, it well be call from an other methode

Comment: Could you fix all the spelling mistakes in your question, and format it into paragraphs? It's difficult to understand right now.

Comment: How did the connection not work?

Comment: You can not use the `this` member in a static method.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you were able to create a minimal example of what you're experiencing so that we might be able to really help you.

Comment: @Engine Since the question itself isn't very helpful, I'll assume from the title that you're trying to connect a signal to a slot from within a static method. You need to call `QObject::connect(QObject*, SIGNAL, QObject*, SLOT)` statically. Note that you'll need to have access to the objects you're connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your connect:

```
connect( roiPopup->getsaveROIButton(), SIGNAL( clicked(         ) ),
         this                        , SLOT  ( saveROI( cv::Mat ) ) );
```

I intentionally reformatted it to show a couple of things:

1. You are trying to connect `clicked` which has no parameters to your slot `saveROI` which expects a parameter. This does not work because the connection does not know where to get the value for `cv::Mat` for. 
   Instead, you need to make a slot which does not retrieve parameters either.
2. As already pointed out by ahenderson in a comment, you cannot use `this` from within a static method.

The main question is, why do you need a static method? Because you only want a single popup window? If that is the only reason, this is the way you would normally do it:

MainThread.h:

```
class klassePopup;  // Note: This is a "forward declaration". 
                    //       Google it if you don't know what that is.

class MainThread : public QObject // or anything else which inherits QObject
{
public:
    MainThread();
    ~MainThread();

public:
    void popup(); // not static

private slots:
    saveROI(); // no parameter

private:
    klassePopup* _roiPopup;
};
```

MainThread.cpp:

```
#include "klassePopup.h"
#include "SavingROI.h"

MainThread::MainThread() :
   _roiPopup( new SavingROI() )
{
    bool bConnectionSucceeded
        = connect( _roiPopup->getsaveROIButton(), SIGNAL( clicked() ),
                 ( this                         , SLOT  ( saveROI() ) );
}

MainThread::~MainThread()
{
    delete _roiPopup;
}

void MainThread::popup()
{
    _roiPopup.show();
}

void MainThread::saveROI()
{
    // retrieve your cv::mat parameter from somewhere else
}
```

This solution would work, but if you want to call that from a static method, you have to create your MainThread instance in that static method as well.

Comment: thanks so much for your help the popup method sould be call from cvSetMouseCallBack that's why I need it to be static

Comment: was your problem solved ?