# how to interact with QPushButton in a static Method

Tags: c++, qt

I have Popup window with 2 button and I want to use the SIGNAL and SLOT of those buttons in a static Methode when I use

```
connect(allbox->getAcceptButton(),SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(dosmt());
```

the program crashs any Idea how I can solve this.
thanks for your help

Comment: Your code sample isn't really large enough to help you with.

Comment: What does your `connect` statement return? (true or false). Maybe the connection is set up correctly but something else is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a slot which calls the static method

Answer (score 0):

You have already asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319629/how-do-i-connect-a-signal-to-a-slot-in-a-static-method), and the answer is the same:  You cannot use `this` in a static method, so you will have to pass an object that has a `dosmt()` slot to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Test: public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
 ...
 public:
     static void testMethod();
 public slots:
     void testSlot();

 };

Test::Test()
{
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
}

Test::testSlot()
{
    Test::testMethod();
}
```

just a short example, you have to connect a SIGNAL with a SLOT as it is documented by Qt http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/signalsandslots.html

Comment: if I want to use the button now in testMethod, I just have to to add it in it ?

Comment: I have to, because I'm using it in a method that been called from cvMousecallback

Comment: You dont have to connect the button with a slot in a static method ;)  I think you did not understand the idea behind signals and slots.

Comment: @ hennaldo I still can't connect my button in this static method

     void Test::testMethod{
          connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),button,SLOT(testslot))) doesn't work ? 
      }

Comment: The QObject::connect method connects the button::clicked() with a slot. So if you press the button the slot will be executed. I dont get your problem.

Comment: I want to catch the SIGNAL of this Button in my static method ? and than run the slot

Comment: But you need to understand: You MUST connect the SIGNAL of the Button with a SLOT. In this SLOT you can do whatever you want (Perhaps call the static method)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22817/discussion-between-hennaldo-and-engine)

Comment: to call my button fram the static method